# How to count values from one table and update another table on same server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in the same server

1. Attendance table
2. Payroll table

How to count present/absent from attendance table in (employee database) and update that count info payroll table in (payroll database) on the same server?

Please help me to solve this problem.

**Attendance** table:

[image]

**Payroll** table:

[image]

Comment: Downvote reason: You've been a member long enough to know [ask].

Comment: what you tried post your code

Comment: How do you define "Absent"? Persons with both `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` equal to `NULL`? The dates in there are total bull though.

Comment: Dear Jens, I want total count of "P"  from attendance table to be updated in the Presents columns of Payroll table empid wise. I tried many time it is showing sum of all employees in attendance table as shown in payroll table's presents column 6369.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH X
AS(
    SELECT
         EmpId
        ,COUNT(EntryType) 'P_Count'
    FROM
        dbo.Attendance
    WHERE
        EntryType = 'P'
    GROUP BY
        EmpId
)
UPDATE
    P
SET
    P.Presents  = X.P_Count
FROM
    dbo.PayRoll P
INNER JOIN
    X       A   ON A.EmpId = P.EmpId
```

Comment: Problem Solved.

Comment: If my answer proved useful can you mark it as Accepted please?